# How to get css islolation random string

Tags: asp.net-core, jquery-selectors, razor-pages, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I use CSS isolation.
This is the output html code:

```
<div b-1yc1hoca3 class="test">Text</div>
```

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Random string that CSS isolation generates is: `b-1yc1hoca3`
I add some html code after page loaded.

```
$('#main').append(`<div class="test">Text</div>`);
```

When above codes will be add, above codes doesn't have CSS isolation random string (`b-1yc1hoca3`) and CSS codes doesn't apply to the element.
How can I get CSS isolation random string with `JQuery` to added to below codes:

```
$('#main').append(`<div class="test">Text</div>`);
```

Just only thing I need is `b-1yc1hoca3`.
For example

```
var cssIsolationRandomString = $('.test').attr('cssIsloationRandomString');
$('#main').append(`<div ${cssIsolationRandomString} class="test">Text</div>`);
```

As far as I know, all CSS isolation random string starts with `b-`.
The problem is `CSS isolation random strings` are random strings and I don't know how to get a random attribute that start with `b-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I found a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33446) here which mentioned `CSS isolation is a build time process` , and the isolation string is [generated by framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#css-isolation-bundling).

> Within the bundled file, each component is associated with a scope
> identifier. For each styled component, an HTML attribute is appended
> with the format b-{STRING}, where the {STRING} placeholder is a
> ten-character string generated by the framework.

Therefore, we can't use Jquery to generate the random string and use it when append the dynamic content. But I found that the random string in the page are the same when the page is rendered. So when we append the dynamic content, we can first to get the `b-{string}` from the initial existed DOM element, then use it in the new content, this worked for me.

[image]

```
<div id="dynamicContent">
    <p id="targetItem">hello this is content in red</p>
</div>
<button id="add">add section</button>

@section Scripts{
     <script>
        $("#add").click(function(){
            var attrs = document.getElementById("targetItem").attributes;
            console.info(attrs);
            var isolation = "";
            $.each(attrs,function(i,elem){
                if (elem.name.startsWith("b-")){
                    isolation = elem.name;
                }
            });
            $('#dynamicContent').append("<p "+isolation+" >added content</p>");
        })
    </script>
}
```

[image]