# How to get the CSS Isolation identifier from within the razor view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application that has CSS isolation turned on. This web app is using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

My styles are stored in the isolated CSS file `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml.css`.

The DataTables data is being loaded via Ajax. The tables rows are not being created with the the isolation attribute because DataTables is not aware of that technology.

I would like to add the isolation attribute when the row is created (via the `createdRow` function callback provided by DataTables), but I can not figure out how to obtain the css isolation identifier within the Razor view.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, `CSS isolation` will create random string and it will work only the css within the application but jquery datatable script generates dynamic script and `CSS isolation` will not work. You can [`check more details here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#css-isolation)

Comment: I am well aware of how both ASPNET CSS Isolation and DataTables work.  That is why my question is "How to get the CSS Isolation Identifier from within a Razor view?"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have came accross [`this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209175/how-to-get-css-islolation-random-string) where a contributor has shown about the css isolation but that's not using datatable. [`You could refer that`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209175/how-to-get-css-islolation-random-string).